# PHP doesn't show line break in textarea value in echo

Tags: php, string, textarea, line-breaks

I am creating a `post_blog.php` file where user will enter all fields one by one like `post_title`, `post_author` etc.

When user write post_text which contains many paragraphs and i get that text by using post method in php it displays me all value in plain text . it do not contain any paragraphs etc.

Here is the code :

```
<textarea rows="400" cols="100" name="post_text">
Enter post text here .. upto 5000 characters . 
</textarea>
```

in php :

```
if()....

echo        $post_text = $_POST['post_text'];
```

Demo Input in post_text:

```
Enter post text here 
.. upto 
5000 
characters .
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter post text here .. upto 5000 characters .
```

Expected OUTPUT :

```
Enter post text here 
.. upto 
5000 
characters .
```

Comment: The text contain break line `\n` that you should convert it to `br` in html

Comment: Attach html tags to  newlines. 
`nl2br` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

When user press Enter, line break `\n` inserted in string but in html doesn't show. You should convert it to `<br>` to showing in html. The `str_replace()` can replace it in string.

```
$newStr = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $str)
```

Also you can use native function [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) that inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in string as @VictorFedorenko mentioned in comment

```
$newStr = nl2br($str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't in the php; Your problem is that HTML doesn't accept white spaces (line breaks, sapces, etc.) and display them as one space. There are some solutions:

Use the `<pre>` tag, which shows the text as-is:

```
<?php

...
echo '<pre>' . $post_text = $_POST['post_text'] . '</pre>';
```

Use the CSS `white-space: pre;` definition, which is excatly like the `<pre>` tag, except that it's can be applied to any element, and you cannot style a `<pre>` tag:

```
<?php

...
echo '<div style="white-space: pre;">' . $post_text = $_POST['post_text'] . '</div>';
```

See [MDN Docs about CSS' `white-space` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

The last solution is to replace any line break with the `<br>` tag and any space with `&nbsp;`:

```
<?php

...
echo $post_text = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', str_replace('\n', '<br>', $_POST['post_text']));
```